# Short story: post-climate-change, mega-rich underwater retreat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story from a pretty recent collection (sometime in the past 5-10 years).

The plot involves 2 people in a sub (some sort of male consultant/operative/spy, and a female pilot), in a world where climate change means really hot temperatures and permanent typhoons everywhere, so people live underwater.

The operative refers to an incident where a mob of people at an airport kill a wealthy family who are waiting for a private jet. (IIRC some sort of eco-terrorist group instigated this).

The two in the sub find a secretly-built underwater complex that was assembled by some mega-rich, then the operative kills the pilot (because he's been employed by the owner of the complex).